# How can I re-ask a question from a different Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, help

How can I ask a question on **Super User** if I have already asked it on **Stack Overflow**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag your question for moderator attention and request that it be moved to Super User. Also make a comment you want it moved and 5 3K+ users can vote to have it migrated to Super User or vice versa.

Asking the same question on two sites are strongly discouraged and they will all generally be migrated to a single site.

Comment: I wonder what should be done if there isn't a migration path between two sites (e.g. SO to math.SE or gamedev.SE).

Comment: @Kenny. Delete the question on the first site and re-ask on the second. However, if the question is not a direct copy & paste it should be fairly OK. We will however have issues with exact, copy and paste cross posts.