# Help tidy up the [help] tag on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, clean-up

I suggested a wiki excerpt for [help](/questions/tagged/help) (here on Meta):

> For questions relating to in-built help features, such as the editor and search help menus.

This seemed sensible to me because it's the only legitimate use of the tag here that I could think of.

But looking at the (currently 37) questions tagged [help](/questions/tagged/help), a good number use [help](/questions/tagged/help) in place of or in addition to [support](/questions/tagged/support). This seems redundant, and I think where appropriate it should be either removed altogether or replaced with a tag which better describes the question.

Additionally, as per the following questions regarding other sites, [help](/questions/tagged/help) as a meta-tag (as opposed to a Meta Stack Overflow tag) should not be used:

> - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80288/burninate-the-help-tag
> - [The [help] tag needs somebody](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98737/the-help-tag-needs-somebody)
> - [Please blacklist the [help] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102165/please-blacklist-the-help-tag)

*(It appears there is no non-meta usage of the tag elsewhere.)*

I suggest we follow suit here on Meta and purge [help](/questions/tagged/help) whereever it is used as a meta-tag.

### Examples

**Legitimate** uses of [help](/questions/tagged/help):

> - [Advanced search help should be available by the search box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114358/advanced-search-help-should-be-available-by-the-search-box)
> - [Add tag referencing to Editing Help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81419/add-tag-referencing-to-editing-help-page)
> - [Add information about backticks to comment help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77838/add-information-about-backticks-to-comment-help)

**Illegitimate** uses of [help](/questions/tagged/help):

- Redundant usage:

  > - [How do I log in to my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73749/how-do-i-log-in-to-my-account)
  > - [How can I re-ask a question from a different Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69564/how-can-i-re-ask-a-question-from-a-different-stack-exchange-site)
- Meta-tag usage:

  > - [When and how to help someone in over their head?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109019/when-and-how-to-help-someone-in-over-their-head)
  > - [Is there a way to prevent Stack Overflow from becoming a code generator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79071/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-stack-overflow-from-becoming-a-code-generator)
  > - [How can I write better questions? / Get more answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75577/how-can-i-write-better-questions-get-more-answers)
  > - [What advice would you give beginners joining a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/what-advice-would-you-give-beginners-joining-a-stack-exchange-site)

I propose we remove or replace the illegitimate uses of the tag (whichever is appropriate on a case-by-case basis), as described above. Does this make sense? Should we do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if we burn `[help]` and directly extend the `[faq]`, which does have the same purpose?